# Specifying step in Sass @for loop

Tags: css, sass

How do I achieve `$i in [2,4,6,8]` in Sass?
Here's what I tried:

```
@for $i from 2 through 8 step 2 {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly there isn't a step feature, instead you're going to do a small hack to confuse the system.

To build on your `for` statement, if you add an `if` statement to check if the number is divisable by 2, it should give you what you want.

```
@for $i from 2 through 8 {
  @if $i % 2 == 0 {
    // do stuff
  }  
}
```

The other way is to use a while statement:

```
$i: 2;
@while $i < 9 {
  // do stuff
  $i: $i + 2;
}
```